# Apache serves blank page

Tags: php, apache

I have created one sample PHP script to upload excel sheets of very bigger sizes. Also the process happening with each records given in the excel sheets is bit complex. To allow bigger sizes, I have added necessary PHP ini values in the Apache configuration file to override the actual PHP ini values.

The problem is, once I upload the bigger files, it takes longer time say 2 minutes or so, after that i am seeing the blank page instead of results page. When I tailed the Apache logs, I didn't see any such lines related to this issue.

Just wanted to know, are there any case/possibilities when Apache could serves blank page?

But when I tailed my application level logs, it is very clear the script has completes the job perfectly. My suspect, may be what could have happen is, once the job completes, while Apache about to serve back the results page something would have happened, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's not Apache's fault and your browser just times out the connection. You could try some of [these](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?PreventingBrowserTimeout) techniques and see if that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible than an "else"-case is not properly handled? You might assume the file was uploaded successfully, but that doesn't necessarily mean it did. Did you only increase the 'upload_max_filesize' or also the 'post_max_size' (the grand total of all your forms: input text + files)?

Try adding the following on the top of your script, to see any errors or warnings PHP might show.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I am sure that the script has uploaded the file successfully and even it completes the tasks it supposed to do. Also I have overrided the post max size value in apache conf file. All the error flags has been turned on.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to take some time to process a request/upload, you may want to consider creating a queue, where the user knows the file was successfully uploaded, and must just wait (can check status on a page perhaps); and you have a cronjob/background process to convert the file(s) and update them.  This way it doesn't waste the users time at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a memory problem, try increasing memory_limit or optimizing your memory usage

Memory allocation/segfaults errors results on blank pages and no log information.

Comment: Make sure your have display_errors=On on your php.ini to see the fatal error.

Answer (score -1):

You can do two thing to avoid this problem

1. Ask user to convert excel file into csv if possible in your situation. as csv are much lighter than excel sheet.
2. try using header("newpage.php") in the script to redirect user to new page

Comment: The requirement is to allow the user to upload both csv and excel file.